# segmentation fault while parsing a list of integers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
       int num_arrays;
       char *p[20];
       char tempc;       
       int i=0;
       do
       { p[i]=malloc(sizeof(int));
        scanf("%s",p[i]);
        tempc=*p[i];
        ++i;
        }while(tempc=='x');
        num_arrays=atoi(p[0]);
```

When i write `num_arrays=atoi(..)`,gcc give me segmentation fault or memory 
stack is exceeded, I don't understand why it behaves like that
can anyone explain, why?

Comment: sorry,iforget to write "p[i]=malloc(sizeof(int));"
i have rewrote my question,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You haven't allocated any memory in `p`, so its elements point to random locations. You can allocate memory for strings with a maximum length of 100 like this:</strike>

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  p[i] = malloc(101);
```

Or else you want an array of *characters*, not of strings, in which case you should declare it like

```
char p[20];
```

In this case, you must not try to read strings into each element with scanf though.

**Update** after the missing code part has been added:

You are allocating `sizeof(int)` bytes of memory for your strings, which is most likely 4, i.e. your input strings read by `scanf` must not be longer than 3 characters. Otherwise you have a buffer overrun error, which may lead to the segmentation fault you are struggling with.

Moreover, `tempc=p[i]` assigns a pointer value to a character variable! This value, converted to a character, will almost surely never be equal to `'x'`.

I guess you are trying to get the first character of `p[i]`, which would be `p[i][0]` or `*p[i]`.

I also suspect that your loop condition is the opposite of what you had in mind: right now the loop repeats as long as `tempc`  is equal to `'x'` - you probably wanted to repeat *until*  `tempc`  becomes `'x'`. And you should also check for your loop not running more than 20 times:

```
  ...
}while(tempc != 'x' && i < 20);
```

Comment: //while writing that question , i forget but in my real code ,i have allocated memeory

Comment: @gcc, see my update. I recommend you to double check your code before posting in the future :-)

Answer (score 4):

You are not allocating memory for your strings.  (**Edit:** Now you are)

You may also want to make sure you are not doing more than 20 iterations since your array of char* only has 20 elements.

Also assuming sizeof(int) == 4, your strings must not be greater than 4 chars as you have now and 1 of those needs to be a null termination.  You may want to allocate more room for those input strings.